# Excel Power Query for Merging multiple sheets into one

Tags: excel, powerquery

How to automate merging of multiple sheets into one sheet in excel before cleaning the data?
Scenerio: I want to setup a query which will clean the data automatically of incoming excel files. The problem I am facing here is that the incoming excel files have three worksheets and I need to combine all those worksheets into one sheet before processing it.

I tried to find the solution online but all I could find was how to combine multiple sheets into one WHEN THE DATA SOURCE IS A SINGLE WORKBOOK. BUT IN MY CASE, THE DATA SOURCE IS A FOLDER WHICH CONTAINS ALL THE INCOMING EXCEL FILES.

Comment: Did this answer work for you? If so please accept it to mark item as solved

Answer (score 2):

you can TRY THIS IN POWERQUERY TO COMBINE THE FILES OF A DIRECTORY

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\subdirectory\directory"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".xlsx")),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name", "Content"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "GetFileData", each Excel.Workbook([Content],true)),
#"Expanded GetFileData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "GetFileData", {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Name"}, {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Sheet"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded GetFileData",{"Content", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind"}),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Removed Columns"[Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Data", List,List)
in  #"Expanded Data"
```